# Обновление списка словарей удаление старой записи

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Имею список словарей, где значение `My_list` может быть:

```
[
    {user: 'test1' tel: ['1234']},
    {user: 'test2' tel: ['12345', '123', '4589']},
    {user: 'test3' tel: ['123458', '1235']}
]
```

Хочу получить:

```
[
{user: 'test1' tel: ['1234']},
{user: 'test2' tel: ['12345']},
{user: 'test2' tel: ['123']},
{user: 'test2' tel: ['4589']},
{user: 'test3' tel: ['123458']}
{user: 'test3' tel: ['1235']}
]


My_list = [
dict(user=item['attributes']['login'],
     tel=item['attributes']['number']

     )

for item in entry_list
  if item['tel']
]
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Такие задачи легко решаются при помощи модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

res = (pd.DataFrame(data)
         .explode("tel")
         .set_index("user")
         ["tel"]
         .apply(lambda x: [x])
         .reset_index()
         .to_dict("records"))
```

результат:

```
In [231]: res
Out[231]:
[{'user': 'test1', 'tel': ['1234']},
 {'user': 'test2', 'tel': ['12345']},
 {'user': 'test2', 'tel': ['123']},
 {'user': 'test2', 'tel': ['4589']},
 {'user': 'test3', 'tel': ['123458']},
 {'user': 'test3', 'tel': ['1235']}]
```

---

Если же нужно получить телефоны не в списках, а как обычные строки, то решение будет выглядеть гораздо проще:

```
In [232]: res = pd.DataFrame(data).explode("tel").to_dict("records")

In [233]: res
Out[233]:
[{'user': 'test1', 'tel': '1234'},
 {'user': 'test2', 'tel': '12345'},
 {'user': 'test2', 'tel': '123'},
 {'user': 'test2', 'tel': '4589'},
 {'user': 'test3', 'tel': '123458'},
 {'user': 'test3', 'tel': '1235'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Жтож,

```
import operator

a = [
    {'user': 'test1', 'tel': ['1234']},
    {'user': 'test2', 'tel': ['12345', '123', '4589']},
    {'user': 'test3', 'tel': ['123458', '1235']}
]

_t = [{'user': x['user'], 'tel': [y]} for x in a for y in x['tel'][1:] if len(x['tel']) > 1]

[a[i]['tel'].remove(y) for i, x in enumerate(a) for y in x['tel'][1:] if len(x['tel']) > 1]

a += _t
del _t

a.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('user'))

print(a)
```

Comment: а если будет несколько еще ключей, например login, number, как их добавить?

Comment: @OlegKalashnikov, тогда надо идти другим путем, ибо этот подходит под конкретное задание.